# Unit-testing a functions php

Tags: php, database, unit-testing, testing

Im new with unit-testing, I know how to test a function that contains two variables inside the functions, like this example, it contains "$user_id" and "$mysqli".

```
function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
   ...............
    }
```

And my question is, how do i test a function that looks like this? A function with no variables inside the function, it only contains the mysqli connection.

```
 function login_check($mysqli) {
    .......
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Aren't both examples the same thing?  Does the first function use a `return` statement to return the value of the two overloads to the function?

Comment: both of them return something, for the first example i have written this testcase:

$LessThanFive = checkbrute('5', $mysqli);
 $this->assertFalse($LessThanFive);

5 is the $user_id. and mysqli the db connection.

Comment: I dont know how to set up a testcase for the 2nd example, could you please help me

Comment: I can certainly try to help, yes.  I think if you are testing the Sql connection, you should do a comparison then assert what you are expecting like you are currently doing with the `$userid` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing in the `$mysqli` parameter as an overload to the function, wouldn't you be testing *that* connection object?

For example:

```
function login_check($mysqli) {    
    if ($mysqli == null)
       $this->AssertFalse($mysqli //there is no connection object);
    else
       $this->AssertTrue($mysqli //the connection string/object is what I am expecting);
    return $mysqli;
}
```

If you know what you are *expecting* in terms of the connection object, you basically just need to store it to a variable and compare the two.

Comment: Ehh, just saying, you should know, that any function stops its execution after  `return` statement. So you got to perform everything before `return`.

Comment: Oops, I meant to move that down.  Thank you for correcting that.

Comment: no im not testing the mysqli connection, inside function "login_check" there is code and a if, its comparing the db password with the password that a person enteres in. How do i compare them ? the statement return true/false.